# Rails jquery can not load in any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have tried all the solution in stackoverflow but I still have a trouble with jquery load on rails.It works on localhost but not on heroku.

So, here is my `application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

here is `application.css` file

```
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Here is my gem file;

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'json',             '~> 1.8.2'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'

gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'   
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
#//= require turbolinks TO ASSETS gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "mailboxer"
gem "select2-rails"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

and here is my `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />



    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                           'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

The funny thing is, console does not give an error about jquery but my slider does not work. And some of the css changes did not reflect to heroku (I did precompile)

Comment: Try it locally in production mode:  you may get the same problem there and it will be a lot easier to debug.  Also, use the devtools in whichever browser you are using: they will point you to the missing files, and you can work back from there to try to figure out why the file is not there.

Comment: Here is the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.` Why it does not load jquery?. It is listed in the first place in application.js file

Comment: With rails 4 you don't need to precompile assets - you just pop the `rails_12factor` gem in and it should setup your app to both compile the assets on heroku when you push and serve static assets. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: You might want to clean out precompiled assets from your git repository and redeploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Heroku pre-compiles by default, I'd say the error is likely that you have a "polluted" precompiled assets (when you have maybe 8-10 `application.js` variants in `public/assets`).

I could - of course - be completely wrong and will happily remove this post, but you may wish to try:

```
$ rake assets:clean
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Assets"
$ git push heroku master

$ heroku rake assets:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an assets compilation issue. For heroku make sure your production environment is well configured, take a look to your `/config/production.rb`, and make sure you have these configs:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

After check the above configs then make sure your `public/assets` folder is not in `.gitignore`.

Then precompile assets in local for then redeploy to heroku, run the following command:
`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

this may take some minutes, after the process finishes then you can commit and push to heroku:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Precompiled assets for heroku"
git push heroku master
```